# Qt macOS Class is implemented in both

Tags: c++, macos, qt, dylib, lib

I'm porting a Qt5 C++ project (originally build on Windows) to macOS Catalina. It depends on [CuteLogger](https://github.com/dept2/CuteLogger).

It's a work in progress. So far I can build it on macOS, and run also.

However I see the following output:

```
got fallback qt version 0x50f01

0x50f01objc[13940]: Class QMacAutoReleasePoolTracker is implemented in both /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/CuteLogger/x64/libCuteLogger.dylib (0x1075af200) 
and /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/project_x64d/project.app/Contents/MacOS/project (0x101db8c70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[13940]: Class QT_ROOT_LEVEL_POOL__THESE_OBJECTS_WILL_BE_RELEASED_WHEN_QAPP_GOES_OUT_OF_SCOPE is implemented in both /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/CuteLogger/x64/libCuteLogger.dylib (0x1075af278) 
and /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/project_x64d/project.app/Contents/MacOS/project (0x101db8ce8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[13940]: Class KeyValueObserver is implemented in both /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/CuteLogger/x64/libCuteLogger.dylib (0x1075af2a0) 
and /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/project_x64d/project.app/Contents/MacOS/project (0x101db8d10). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

objc[13940]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/CuteLogger/x64/libCuteLogger.dylib (0x1075af2f0) 
and /Users/user/QtProjects/Project/project_x64d/project.app/Contents/MacOS/project (0x101db8d60). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

What is that?

I'm new to macOS development but I saw I can inspect a binary with `otool`. So I did and found the `.dylib` seems to point to it self (check the first line), is that normal?

```
otool -L x64d/libCuteLogger.dylib 
x64d/libCuteLogger.dylib:
    @rpath/libCuteLogger.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1894.60.100)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59306.140.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1069.24.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1677.104.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1677.104.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 902.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

And then the main app also points to the `.dylib`

```
otool -L project.app/Contents/MacOS/project 
project.app/Contents/MacOS/project:
    @rpath/libCuteLogger.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Versions/A/CoreMedia (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1000.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Carbon (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 162.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.11.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo (compatibility version 1.2.0, current version 1.5.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.14.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 212.8.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 64.0.0, current version 1355.22.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1061.141.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit (compatibility version 45.0.0, current version 1894.60.100)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 59306.140.5)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 52.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1069.24.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1677.104.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1677.104.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 902.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 4.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
```

Comment: It looks like you included same source files and into library target and into main app target which uses that library. As they are visible from library you can remove them from app target and import symbols from library.

Comment: By source files, you mean cutelogger .cpp files being included in the main project? I don't see that here. Any additional tips on how to investigate the issue?